# delete objects from lists in selectable datatable

Tags: flutter, dart

i am beginner in FLutter and i have created an app that get a list of players from an api and then filters the list of players by their position , everything is working perfect , except one little thing , every time when i select a player and add it to selectedPlayers List and then if i click again and this player is still selected it must not appear in the list again until i unselect this player then player must appear again ,
My problem is that the players that are selected are not deleting in the list and i have a problem of duplicate , i am trying to find a solution for this problem

***Tip:*** int ***_playerID*** is ***unique*** for every ***Playerr***

My Playerr model class:

```
class Playerr {
  //unique field
  int _playerID;
  String _firstName;
  String _lastName;
  String _position;
  String _team;
  double _price = 5;
  String rating;
  int _appearances = 0;
  int _goals = 0;
  int _assists = 0;
  int _cleanSheets = 0;
  int _redCards = 0;
  int _yellowCards = 0;
  String _image;

  Playerr(this._playerID, this._firstName, this._lastName, this._position,
      this._team,
      this.rating, this._appearances, this._goals, this._assists,
      this._cleanSheets, this._redCards,
      this._yellowCards) {

    if (_position == ("Goalkeeper")) {
      this._image = "assets/goal.png";
    } else {
      this._image = "assets/shirt" + team.toString() + ".png";
    }

    if(rating == null){
      rating = "5.000000";
      _price = 3;
    }else if((double.parse(rating) >= 6.0) && (double.parse(rating) < 7.0)){
    _price = 6;
    }else if((double.parse(rating) >= 7.0) && (double.parse(rating) < 8.0)){
      _price = 15;
    }else if(double.parse(rating) >= 8.0){
      _price = 30;
    }
    if(appearances == null){
      appearances = 0;
    }

    if(redCards == null){
      redCards = 0;
    }

    if(yellowCards == null){
      yellowCards = 0;
    }

    if(price == null){
      price = 0;
    }

    if(goals == null){
      goals = 0;
    }else if(goals>=5 && goals < 10){
      price+=5;
    }else if(goals>=10 && goals <20){
      price+=10;
    }else if(goals>=20){
      price+=20;
    }
    if(assists == null){
      assists = 0;
    }else if(assists >= 5 && assists <10){
      price+=5;
    }else if(assists >= 10 && assists <20){
      price+=10;
    }else if(assists >= 10){
      price+=20;
    }

    if(cleanSheets == null){
      cleanSheets = 0;
    }else if(cleanSheets >= 30){
      price+=15;
    }

  }

  factory Playerr.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Playerr(int.parse(json['player']['id']), json['player']['firstname'], json['player']['lastname'],
     json['statistics'][0]['games']['position'],
     json['statistics'][0]['team']['name'],
        json['statistics'][0]['games']['rating'],
        int.parse(json['statistics'][0]['games']['appearances']),
        int.parse(json['statistics'][0]['goals']['total']),
         int.parse(json['statistics'][0]['goals']['assists']), int.parse(json['statistics'][0]['goals']['saves']),
        int.parse(json['statistics'][0]['cards']['yellow']), int.parse(json['statistics'][0]['cards']['red']));
  }

  Playerr.empty() {
    this.image = "assets/shirt_blank.png";
    this.firstName = "firstname";
    this.lastName = "lastname";
  }

  String get image => _image;

  set image(String value) {
    _image = value;
  }

 

  int get yellowCards => _yellowCards;

  set yellowCards(int value) {
    _yellowCards = value;
  }

  int get redCards => _redCards;

  set redCards(int value) {
    _redCards = value;
  }

  int get cleanSheets => _cleanSheets;

  set cleanSheets(int value) {
    _cleanSheets = value;
  }

  int get assists => _assists;

  set assists(int value) {
    _assists = value;
  }

  int get goals => _goals;

  set goals(int value) {
    _goals = value;
  }

  
  int get appearances => _appearances;

  set appearances(int value) {
    _appearances = value;
  }
  

  
  double get price => _price;

  set price(double value) {
    _price = value;
  }


  String get team => _team;

  set team(String value) {
    _team = value;
  }

  String get position => _position;

  set position(String value) {
    _position = value;
  }

  String get lastName => _lastName;

  set lastName(String value) {
    _lastName = value;
  }

  String get firstName => _firstName;

  set firstName(String value) {
    _firstName = value;
  }

  int get playerID => _playerID;

  set playerID(int value) {
    _playerID = value;
  }

  String get fullName => _firstName + " " + _lastName;
}
```

Here screen captures that shows what i did

[image]

[image]

afer i selected the first player on the list

i go to choose another player and i still find him not deleted ,

[image]

which mean i have duplicate players , i need to make sure that i do not have any copy of any player when he is selected , and i need also to make sure that after the player is deleted that he will come back to the list when he is replaced and not in selectedPlayers anymore ,

Here the full code of the api and the selection and filter of players:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Fantazyy/Playerrs.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Fantazyy/club_api.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Fantazyy/create_team_view.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Fantazyy/player%20copy.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Fantazyy/player_lab.dart';
import 'package:footyappp/Key/Key.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class PlayersCreationDetailsView extends StatefulWidget {

  final List<Playerr> selectedPlayers;
  final int playerIndex;

  const PlayersCreationDetailsView ({
    Key key,
    @required this.selectedPlayers,
    @required this.playerIndex
  })  : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState createState() => _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState();
}


class _PlayersCreationDetailsViewState extends State<PlayersCreationDetailsView> {
  bool _sortAsc = false;
  int _sortColumnIndex = 0;
  double _columnWidth  = 40.0;
  double _columnNameWidth  = 60.0;
  double _columnPosWidth  = 80.0;
  PlayersDataSource _playersDataSource;
  List<Playerr> _players = [];
  List<ClubApi> selectedClubs = [];
  List<int> clubIdentifiers = [];
  List<Playerrs> playersjson = [];
  List<Playerr> playersApi = [];
    List<dynamic> playerList ;
   List _table;


  int _rowsPerPage = 20;
   final String apiUrl =
      "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/players?season=2020&league=39";
  
  static const headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "v3.football.api-sports.io",
    //Always make sure to check the api key and the limit of a request in a free api
    'x-rapidapi-key': "f6ebead51a2ade65b73948c623b1da95"
  };

  void _sort<T>(Comparable<T> getField(Playerr p), int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
    _playersDataSource._sort<T>(getField, ascending);
    setState(() {
      _sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
      _sortAsc = ascending ;
    });
  }


  Future<void> getClubIds() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/teams?season=2020&league=39",
        headers: {'x-rapidapi-host': "v3.football.api-sports.io",
          'x-rapidapi-key': ApiKey.key});
    String body = response.body;
    var data = jsonDecode(body);
    List<dynamic> table = data['response'];

    setState(() {
      selectedClubs = table
          .map((dynamic item) => ClubApi.fromJson(item))
          .toList();

      for(var item in selectedClubs){
         clubIdentifiers.add(item.team.id);
      }

      for(var item in clubIdentifiers){
        print("club id"+item.toString());
        this.getPlayer(item);
      }

    });

  }


  Future<void> getPlayer(int id) async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
      "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/players?season=2020&league=39&team=$id",
        headers: {'x-rapidapi-host': "v3.football.api-sports.io",
    'x-rapidapi-key': ApiKey.key});
    String body = response.body;
    var data = jsonDecode(body);
    List<dynamic> table = data['response'];

    setState(() {
      playersjson = table
          .map((dynamic item) => Playerrs.fromJson(item))
          .toList();

      for(var item in playersjson){
        String pos = item.statistics[0].games.position.toString().substring(8);
        playersApi.add(Playerr(item.player.id,item.player.firstname, item.player.lastname, pos,
            item.statistics[0].team.name,item.statistics[0].games.rating, item.statistics[0].games.appearences,item.statistics[0].goals.total,
            item.statistics[0].goals.assists,item.statistics[0].goals.conceded,
            item.statistics[0].cards.red, item.statistics[0].cards.yellow));
      }
      print(playersApi.length);
      // for(var item in playersApi){
      //   print("position"+item.position.toString());
      // print(item.position.contains("DEFENDER"));
      // }
      for(var item in playersApi){
        print("position"+item.position.toString());

      }
      if (widget.playerIndex < 2) {
        _players = playersApi.where((player) => player

            .position.contains("GOALKEEPER")).toList();
      } else if (widget.playerIndex < 7) {
        _players = playersApi.where((player) => player.position.contains("DEFENDER")).toList();
      } else if (widget.playerIndex < 12) {
        _players = playersApi.where((player) => player.position.contains("MIDFIELDER")).toList();
      } else {
        _players = playersApi.where((player) => player.position.contains("ATTACKER")).toList();
      }
      //filter out players who are already selected

        for (Playerr player in widget.selectedPlayers) {
          _players.remove(player);
        }
        _playersDataSource = PlayersDataSource(widget.playerIndex, widget.selectedPlayers, _players, context);

    });

  }

@override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  this.getClubIds();
    //filter out players by position

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(playersApi.length);

    return  playersApi.length == 0
        ? Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
            Color(0xFFe70066),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
        : WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            PaginatedDataTable(
              columnSpacing: 1.0,
              horizontalMargin: 1.0,
              availableRowsPerPage: [10,20,50],
              rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
              onRowsPerPageChanged: (int value) { setState(() { _rowsPerPage = value; }); },
              sortColumnIndex: _sortColumnIndex,
              sortAscending: _sortAsc,
              header: Text("Players"),
              columns: <DataColumn>[
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: Text("First Name", softWrap: true,)),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.firstName, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: Text("Last Name", softWrap: true,)),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.lastName, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: Text("Position", softWrap: true,)),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.position, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                  new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Price")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.price, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: Text("Rating", softWrap: true,)),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.rating, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
               /* new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Position")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.position, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),*/
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Team")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<String>((Playerr p) => p.team, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Apps")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.appearances, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
              
               /* new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Points")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.points, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Week Points")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.pointsWeek, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),*/
               
               /* new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnWidth , child: new Text("Sub Apps")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player p) => p.subAppearances, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),*/
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Goals")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.goals, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Assists")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.assists, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Clean")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.cleanSheets, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Yellows")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.yellowCards, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
                new DataColumn(
                    label: new Container(width: _columnPosWidth , child: new Text("Reds")),
                    numeric: true,
                    onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Playerr p) => p.redCards, columnIndex, ascending)
                ),
               
              ],
              source: _playersDataSource,
            )
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class PlayersDataSource extends DataTableSource {

  PlayersDataSource(this._playerIndex, this._selectedPlayers, this._players, this.context);

  int _playerIndex;
  List<Playerr> _players;
  List<Playerr> _selectedPlayers;

  int _selectedCount = 0;
  var context;
  double _columnWidth  = 40.0;
  double _columnNameWidth  = 60.0;
  double _columnPosWidth  = 80.0;

  void _sort<T>(Comparable<T> getField(Playerr p), bool ascending) {
    _players.sort((Playerr a, Playerr b) {
      if (!ascending) {
        final Playerr c = a;
        a = b;
        b = c;
      }
      final Comparable<T> aValue = getField(a);
      final Comparable<T> bValue = getField(b);
      return Comparable.compare(aValue, bValue);
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }

  DataCell getCell(String text) {
    return DataCell(Container(width: _columnPosWidth, child: Text(text, overflow: TextOverflow.fade, softWrap: false,)));
  }

  


  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    assert(index >= 0);
    if (index >= _players.length)
      return null;
    final Playerr player = _players[index];
    return DataRow.byIndex(
      onSelectChanged: (bool) {
        _players.removeAt(index);
        _selectedPlayers[_playerIndex] = player;
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {return CreateTeamView(players: _players, selectedPlayers: _selectedPlayers,);}));
      },
        index: index,
        cells: <DataCell>[
          getCell(player.firstName),
          getCell(player.lastName),
          getCell(player.position),
         getCell('${player.price}'),
          getCell('${player.rating}'),
         // getCell('${player.isFresher}'),
          getCell('${player.team}'),
          //getCell('${player.points}'),
         // getCell('${player.pointsWeek}'),
          getCell('${player.appearances}'),
         // getCell('${player.subAppearances}'),
          getCell('${player.goals}'),
          getCell('${player.assists}'),
          getCell('${player.cleanSheets}'),
         // getCell('${player.motms}'),
          getCell('${player.yellowCards}'),
          getCell('${player.redCards}'),
        //  getCell('${player.ownGoals}'),
        ]
    );
  }

  @override
  int get rowCount => _players.length;

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;

  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => _selectedCount;


}
```

I am really stuck and comfused , still the problem comfuses me,  the players are coming from api json and there is no duplicate at all , i am speaking here about the list of api must not show again a player that is already selected and pushed to selectedPlayers but it must show it again when the player is not in the list selectedPlayers anymore.
Any help will really so useful and so appreciated

***Tip:***
*the file **CreateTeamView** is the file that has a UI with length of 16 (the stadium in the picture above) that in every click on any index , the code above is just the code of datatable of the players , it will be called everytime , the problem is that i don't want the list to have all the same players in everytime , i need to make the _players filter it self by deleting all the players that the list selectedPlayers contains , and second thing im searching is when i replace a player that was existing in selectedPlayers list : i want to make it back to the _players list , i hope this is clear , i know it's hard to understand my goal*

Comment: in your second picture, when  check box is clicked, the selected row become duplicate instead of delete ?

Comment: without even clicking the checkbox ,clicking the row will select the player , but after i go to choose another player that have the same player position , i find that the selected players , still exist in the _players lists :  the players  that are selected are in SelectedPlayers List, and the other are in _players list, what i want is when i select a player and add it to the selectedPlayers List then delete the player from _players list, and when i go to a player that is already exist in SelectedPlayers and unselect: i want that player to go back to _players : only the selection works

Comment: On `onSelectChanged` function are you adding new player to the `selectedPlayers` list or changing one player to another ?

Comment: in selectedPlayers i am adding new players but in the same time changing some player to other , for example if i select a certain player at a certain index , if i select that index again the player will be replaced , but in case i select an empty index then i push the new player ; the problem is that the code above is called every time i click an index in another file , which means the api will not filter the selectedPlayers in the list , i am searching a way that the _players list delete all players that exists in selectedPlayers list

Comment: the file CreateTeamView is the file that has a UI with length of 16 (the stadium in the picture above) that in every click on any index , the code above will be called everytime , the problem is that i don't want the list to have all the same players in everytime , i need to make the _players filter it self by deleting all the players that the list selectedPlayers contains , and second thing im searching is when i replace a player that was existing in selectedPlayers list : i want to make it back to the _players list , i hope this is clear , i know it's hard to understand my goal

Comment: the code that appears is just the code of the datatable that appears after every selection and call , i hope this is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i need to make the _players filter it self by deleting all the players
> that the list selectedPlayers contains

I notice that you have given that `int _playerID is unique for every Playerr` we can make use of this to delete items from `_players`

```
if(!_selectedPlayers.isEmpty){
_selectedPlayers.forEach((selectedPlayer) =>
          _players.removeWhere((player) => player.playerID == selectedPlayer.playerID));
}
```

You can call this above code everytime you do the API call.

> when i replace a player that was existing in selectedPlayers list : i
> want to make it back to the _players list

I don't think this will be an issue now, because you are deleting the players from `_players` based on `selectedPlayers` but if it still is an issue, during replacement, just add the old player to the list

```
_players.add(_replacedPlayer);
```

and you can get the replaced player by storing the player present at that index before assigning the new players

```
_replacedPlayer = _selectedPlayers[_playerIndex];
_selectedPlayers[_playerIndex] = player;
_players.add(_replacedPlayer);
```

---

**OUTDATED**

Just have an `_isSelectedField` in your `Playerr` model and make a getter function and setter function`isSelectedField()` and initialise it to `false` in your `getPlayer()` function's `setState()` because initially no player is selected

```
 bool _isSelectedField;
 bool get isSelectedField => _isSelectedField;

 set isSelectedField (bool value) {
   _isSelectedField = value;
 }
```

The value of this will change according to the value in `DataRow's` `onSelectChanged` callback,
so you can accept the value in `onSelectChanged` and set it to the value.

```
      onSelectChanged: (bool value) {
        player.isSelectedField = value;
        _selectedPlayers[_playerIndex] = player;
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {return CreateTeamView(players: _players, selectedPlayers: _selectedPlayers,);}));
      },
```

And in your `DataRow getRow(int index)` and another if statement

```
...

 DataRow getRow(int index) {
    assert(index >= 0);
    if (index >= _players.length)
      return null;
    final Playerr player = _players[index];
    if (!player.isSelectedField)
      return null;
...
```

Comment: the problem is that the code above is called every time i click an index in another file , which means the api will not filter the selectedPlayers in the list , i am searching a way that the _players list delete all players that exists in selectedPlayers list in every time i call the api

Comment: the file CreateTeamView is the file that has a UI with length of 16 (the stadium in the picture above) that in every click on any index , the code above will be called everytime , the problem is that i don't want the list to have all the same players in everytime , i need to make the _players filter it self by deleting all the players that the list selectedPlayers contains , and second thing im searching is when i replace a player that was existing in selectedPlayers list : i want to make it back to the _players list , i hope this is clear , i know it's hard to understand my goal

Comment: the code that appears is just the code of the datatable that appears after every selection and call , i hope this is clear

Comment: I have tried to answer both your problems, please let me know if that is what you were looking for

Comment: this code should be copied in which part of the document?

Comment: the first part, where I am removing players, can be run after every API call because you have to filter players after every API call right?
the second part can go into `onSelectChanged` of `PlayersDataSource`

Comment: i had an error because some players in selectedPlayers are null , so how to filter and check if the selectedPlayers are not null before filtering the array? because when i have this condition player.playerID == selectedPlayer.playerID and the selectedPlayer is null it leads to error , so how to filter by making sure that this condition works without worry about if the selectedPlayer is null or not?

Comment: just add `if(!_selectedPlayers.isEmpty)` before the `forEach` statement, because we don't have to filter if the `_selectedPlayers` list is empty. I have updated my answer, please check the first code block, I have added the null check now